# Chrome reloads images when generating code contains session_start()

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, firefox

I found a strange issue in Chrome. [Test code](https://szarduma.hu/test.php)

In javascript I insert dynamically generated images into a div, and by button clicks I insert further contents into the same div.

If the image generation code contains session_start(), Chrome (Firefox not) reloads this images on button clicks. If I comment out the session_start() line, neither does Chrome.

Why does Chrome "remember", what was the headers of the previously loaded images? What is the point of this?

Comment: I would be curious to see if the headers, specifically the cache-related ones, are different between the w/ session and w/o session versions. It appears that Chrome is re-loading the entire element and since the images are set to never cache, it appears to be more strict with that interpretation than Firefox, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @ChrisHaas You're right! The guilty header is:
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
But the question remains open. Why does it matter the previously loaded image header? The images in the DOM not modified.

Comment: You are shuffling the container using `innerHTML` is my guess, and I'd be surprised if the spec addresses what browsers should do in that situation specifically. I'd further be curious if you switched to [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) or `appendChild()` if it would behave in a manner that you'd expect across all browsers.

Comment: Yes, if I use append(), it's good, not refreshing.

Comment: Your question was very intriguing to me. Do you think you have enough with the above to post an answer at this point?